# Futurebuilder snapshot has no data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-future

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid.toString();
  var userData;
  var dbFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    dbFuture = getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future getData() async {
    final String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid.toString();
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await users.doc(uid).get();
    users.doc(uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
      userData = doc.data();
      print(doc.data());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: dbFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('waiting'),
                );
              }
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text('error'),
                );
              }
              final data = snapshot.data;
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(userData['displayName']),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut,
                        child: Text("Log out"))
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
      );
```

I'm new in Flutter and trying to make an application for managing an academy.

I successfully saved the data at Firestore Cloud, and I can read them with

```
      print(doc.data());
```

Now I want to build Profile page with those data, so I used Futurebuilder.

But snapshot always has no data.

I read [documents](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) as well, but still have no idea.

Comment: In `getData()`, remove `users.doc(uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {` but retain `userData = doc.data();`. Then return `userData` so that `dbFuture` will have a value, not `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your data from Firebase and display them in your widgets, you have two ways, but you have to choose only one according to your needs.

### With `FutureBuilder()`

This code will call your database and load the info you request at each build and at each `setState()` (responsible for updating your interface content). It could be useful for some data types, but in your case your redundant Firebase calls could cost you.

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late final uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
                future: users.doc(uid).get(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Text('waiting'),
                    );
                  }
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Text('error'),
                    );
                  }

                  return Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(snapshot.data!['some_data']),
                        Text(auth.currentUser?.displayName ?? 'user have no name'),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: auth.signOut,
                            child: Text("Log out"))
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
      );
```

### In the `initState()`

When using `initState()`, the code inside is called only once. To refresh the content, you will have to call `getData()` manually (in a `setState()` for example)

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late final uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;

  String? someData;

  @override
  void initState() {
      getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    users.doc(uid).get().then((doc) {
      someData = doc['some_data'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(someData ?? 'no data'),
            Text(auth.currentUser?.displayName ?? 'user have no name'),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: auth.signOut,
                child: Text("Log out"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Finally, if your users authenticate, you can use `auth.currentUser?.displayName` and `auth.currentUser!.updateDisplayName('new name')` to simply get and change your users' names.